# mySql Database security

Tags: mysql, database-security

I have a database security question. Here is my scenario:

1. I have a CodeIgniter app with an associated mySql database (main) on a private internal server
2. There are several satellite applications which need a subset of the data in the main database

It is imperative the data in the main database isn't compromised. My thoughts were that I need to mirror these subsets of the database in a public location where the satellite apps can access it. This way the communication is unidirectional.

What is the best way to achieve this? What other security measures do you recommend to protect my databases?

Comment: [Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replication.html) is unidirectional, where slave servers receive updates from the master but cannot push changes back in the other direction.  However, you may not need to go that far: have you considered simply creating database users that have only been [granted](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/grant.html) the minimum required [privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/privileges-provided.html)?

Comment: @eggyal I will look into replication.